# CSS Bootstrap subtheme drupal 8

Tags: css, drupal, less, drupal-8

So I've tried to load the css on to my page, but with no luck. I used this approach https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme I am using a sub theme of bootstrap and have this in my

.libraries.yml:

```
global-styling: 
   css: 
     theme: 
         css/style.css: {}
```

and try to change css in style.css but doesn't work.

### My .info.yml has:

```
libraries:
     - 'SUBTHEME/global-styling'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite the'SUBTHEME' word to your theme name. If yout theme name is bootstapsubtheme, you sould write

```
    libraries:
    - 'bootstrapsubtheme/global-styling'
```

Be careful, there is this "SUBTHEME" text in other files, that you sould rewrite to your themename.
And yes, like as they wrote above, you sould switch off the aggregate css and js files in the configuration-> development -> performance menu or clear all cache.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to go to admin > configuration > Development > Performance and uncheck "Aggregate CSS files".

Answer (score 0):

I'd also recommend setting up theme debugging on your local environment: https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/drupal-8-theming-setting-up-theme-debugging (I'm not affiliated with them, just use it all the time).